# Get Week Number of LocalDate (Java 8)

Tags: java, java-8, week-number

I'm trying to get the Week Number of a full LocalDate with the format:

```
dd.MM.yyy
```

I haven't found a function in the Java 8 Date API wich returns the Week Number and i have tried to create a algorithm, but it did'nt work.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

One small warning. I haven't tested this yet, but looking at the API documentation of [`WeekFields`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html) and [`LocalDate.get`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#get-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-), you should do something like:

```
LocalDate date = ...;
// Or use a specific locale, or configure your own rules
WeekFields weekFields = WeekFields.of(Locale.getDefault()); 
int weekNumber = date.get(weekFields.weekOfWeekBasedYear());
```

Comment: Careful about Locale.getDefault(). In some places (e.g Canada) it can return a week that starts on a Sunday. Use "Locale.ISO" for weeks starting on a Monday.

Comment: There is no Locale.ISO, but there is `WeekFields.ISO`

Comment: This is very important to notice. Probably you want to have `WeekFields.ISO`!

Comment: @membersound That depends on whether you want to use the ISO definition, or if you want the rule that is common for your locale.

Comment: Indeed I wasn't aware that eg in the US the first day might often be `Sunday`. Nonetheless, if you develop an application for european customers, but your systems defaults local is `en_US` (which is often the case for developers!), then your result will be different than expected if you didn't notice this.

Comment: One doubt here. How to get the week number in 2 letter. var dateRangeFrom = "20200101" ; var weekFields:WeekFields =  WeekFields.of(Locale.getDefault()); This will provide the result as  Int = 1
.But I want it as Int = 01.

Comment: @abc_spark Integers are never padded. That is a presentation concern that you should handle with a suitable formatter, eg see [How can I pad an integer with zeros on the left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473282/how-can-i-pad-an-integer-with-zeros-on-the-left) and other questions on stack overflow.

Comment: @Mark. Ya. That is correct. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 61):

The answer of Mark Rotteveel is almost right and again an example which kind of confusion potential there is in the class `WeekFields` (similar sounding method names, but deviating from intuitive civil usage). The right code requires another field:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
TemporalField woy = WeekFields.of(Locale.getDefault()).weekOfWeekBasedYear(); 
int weekNumber = date.get(woy);
```

See also the similar debate on this [SO-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25912455/get-the-weeknumber-from-a-given-date-in-java-fx), especially the discussion and comments about the answer of @kleopatra.

Comment: I have updated my answer based on yours. I didn't have access to Java 8 here, so I had to guess (and it looks like I didn't read the [`WeekFields`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html) class documentation to closely, as it does explain this difference.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel OK, you now have my upvote ;-) For me, the name "weekOfWeekBasedYear" is too technical and remains annoying. Even the ISO-8601-paper does not contain this term (it just uses terms like "calendar week" or "week date").

Comment: Careful about Locale.getDefault(). In some places (e.g Canada) it can return a week that starts on a Sunday. Use "Locale.ISO" for weeks starting on a Monday.

Comment: There is no Locale.ISO, but there is `WeekFields.ISO`