# Week-based pattern does not work as expected

Tags: java, date-formatting, java-time, week-number

I expect these two formatters to be equivalent:

```
DateTimeFormatter fromBuilder = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendValue(IsoFields.WEEK_BASED_YEAR, 4)
    .appendLiteral('-')
    .appendValue(IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR, 2)
    .toFormatter();
DateTimeFormatter fromPattern = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-ww");
```

But they do not give the same result:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2017, 1, 1);
System.out.printf("from builder: %s%n", fromBuilder.format(date));  // prints 'from builder: 2016-52'
System.out.printf("from pattern: %s%n", fromPattern.format(date));  // prints 'from pattern: 2017-01'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Your `fromPattern`-formatter is not based on ISO but your default locale settings for first-day-of-week and minimum-days-in-first-calendar-week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Y` and `w` patterns [correspond to a localized version of week-fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendPattern-java.lang.String-), using the JVM's default locale (`java.util.Locale`). The second formatter is equivalent to:

```
// localized week fields (using default Locale)
WeekFields weekFields = WeekFields.of(Locale.getDefault());
// equivalent to YYYY-ww
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendValue(weekFields.weekBasedYear(), 4)
    .appendLiteral('-')
    .appendValue(weekFields.weekOfWeekBasedYear(), 2)
    .toFormatter();
```

As this is locale dependent, it can or can't work like `IsoFields`. The `WeekFields` created above will have a different behaviour depending on the JVM's default locale.

`IsoFields`, on the other hand, follows ISO-8601 definition to define the week-based fields, as [described in the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/IsoFields.html):

> The first week of a week-based-year is the first Monday-based week of the standard ISO year that has at least 4 days in the new year.
>
> - If January 1<sup>st</sup> is Monday then week 1 starts on January 1<sup>st</sup>
> - If January 1<sup>st</sup> is Tuesday then week 1 starts on December 31<sup>st</sup> of the previous standard year
> - If January 1<sup>st</sup> is Wednesday then week 1 starts on December 30<sup>th</sup> of the previous standard year
> - If January 1<sup>st</sup> is Thursday then week 1 starts on December 29<sup>th</sup> of the previous standard year
> - If January 1<sup>st</sup> is Friday then week 1 starts on January 4<sup>th</sup>
> - If January 1<sup>st</sup> is Saturday then week 1 starts on January 3<sup>rd</sup>
> - If January 1<sup>st</sup> is Sunday then week 1 starts on January 2<sup>nd</sup>

As `2017-01-01` is a Sunday, it corresponds to the last line above: week 1 starts on **January 2<sup>nd</sup> 2017**, so **January 1<sup>st</sup> 2017** is still in the last week of 2016.

---

You can check how your `WeekFields` instance differs from `IsoFields` by calling the methods `getFirstDayOfWeek()` and `getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek()` - which are used to [calculate the values of the respecitive week-based fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html):

> A week is defined by:
>
> - The first day-of-week. For example, the ISO-8601 standard considers Monday to be the first day-of-week.
> - The minimal number of days in the first week. For example, the ISO-8601 standard counts the first week as needing at least 4 days.
>
> Together these two values allow a year or month to be divided into weeks.

In the JVM I'm using, the default locale is `pt_BR`, and the `WeekFields` created has the first day-of-week as Sunday, and minimal days in first week as `1`. Check yours and you'll see that it also differs from `IsoFields`.

---

You can check ISO's definition by using the [constant `WeekFields.ISO`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html#ISO): `getFirstDayOfWeek()` returns Monday and `getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek()` returns `4`.

---

Also, remind that there's a small difference between `IsoFields` and `WeekFields.ISO`. Quoting [JodaStephen's comment in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22874374/what-is-the-motivation-for-two-different-week-based-year-definitions-in-jsr-310#comment35229416_23031415):

> The only observable difference was that WeekFields operates on all calendar systems (by converting to ISO) whereas IsoFields only operates on ISO (and rejects other calendar systems)

Comment: Great answer! I can't believe none of this is mentioned in the description of the pattern symbols: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Comment: Follow up question: Is is possible to write a pattern that use ISO week fields?

Comment: @glerup I don't think so, probably the only way is to use a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` with the custom fields.

Comment: @glerup And it's (discretely) mentioned in [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder.appendPattern` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendPattern-java.lang.String-): *"`Y` ... append special **localized** WeekFields element for numeric week-based-year"* etc. But I agree it should be better documented in `DateTimeFormatter` class.

Comment: @glerup One alternative is to use a locale that behaves like ISO and set it in the formatter, such as: `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-ww", Locale.UK)`. But I don't like this solution. I prefer to explicity use `IsoFields` in this case, as the locale doesn't tell (at least in a specific way) that I want to use ISO week-based fields. And I'm not sure if locale-specific behaviour can change among different Java versions (probably not, but anyway, I prefer to not take the risk).